# Can I use enums in Java to define what class to call/use? If so, how?

Tags: java, enums

Is it possible to use enums in Java to define what class I need to call  at runtime?

For example, if I have 3 enums and 3 classes, all using the same interface/common method names, can I evaluate a string, see if it is a valid enum, and then, at runtime, define which class I will use to make my method call?  Is this possible?

For example, my thinking is I could do something like this:

```
private enum animal {
    Duck, Dog, Cat;
}

public isValid(String animal)
{
    for(animal a : animal.values())
    {
        if(a.name().equalsIgnoreCase(animal))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public feedAnimal(String animal)
{
    if(isValid(animal)
    {
        //get class to use
        // call class.feed();
        //maybe do more stuff
    }
}
```

but I'm unsure how really.

Comment: Have each enum hold an object?

Comment: What's wrong with using polymorphism to handle this for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible and btw. I would refactor your code a bit and use some OO concepts here. Take a look below.

The enum:

```
public enum ValidAnimals {
    DUCK(Duck.class),
    DOG(Dog.class);

    private ValidAnimals(Class animal){
        this.animal=animal;
    }
    private Class animal;

    public Class getAnimalClass(){
        return animal;
    }

    public static boolean isValid(Animal otherAnimal) {
        for (ValidAnimals animal : ValidAnimals.values()) {
            if (animal.getAnimalClass() == otherAnimal.getClass()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `Animal` class, which will be used by specific animal types:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void feedAnimal();
}
```

Specific animals examples:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    public void feedAnimal(){
        System.out.println("Feeding dog");
    }
}

public class Duck extends Animal{
    public void feedAnimal(){
        System.out.println("Feeding duck");
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal{
    public void feedAnimal(){
        System.out.println("Feeding cat");
    }
}
```

And the main class that uses all written above:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Duck duck = new Duck();
        Cat cat = new Cat();

        Collection<Animal> hungryAnimals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        hungryAnimals.add(dog);
        hungryAnimals.add(duck);
        hungryAnimals.add(cat);

        for (Animal a: hungryAnimals){
            if (ValidAnimals.isValid(a)){
                a.feedAnimal();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And finally the expected output:

```
    Feeding dog
    Feeding duck
```

The cat is not on the list and it stays hungry